# Is that a valid BFS?

Tags: python, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, graph-traversal

I recently wrote a function to traverse a graph, along those lines:

```
def traverse(batch: list[str], seen: set[str]):
    if not batch:
        return
    new_batch = []
    for node in batch:
        print(node)
        new_batch.extend(n for n in neighbours(node) if n not in seen)
    traverse(new_batch, seen.union(new_batch))

traverse([start_node], {start_node})
```

I didn't give it much thoughts then, but now that I look at it, it looks like this is actually a BFS on the graph.

My question is: is this a correct implementation of a BFS and why do all BFS algorithms employ a queue instead of such a recursion?

Comment: More of a code review question. Generally, iterative implementations will be more performant then recursive ones and, depending on the data, not run into "max recursion depth" errors. Also, it is more reusable as you can just switch the queue for a stack and have a DFS implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, looks like a BFS.

Recursion isn't used as often as with a large enough dataset you'll hit Python's recursion-stack-limit.

Also, using a queue for the BFS makes it easier to switch to different algorithms, such as a DFS or a A*, by using a stack or a sorted list respectively.